# Draw on top of pdfs and images

Tags: angular

My requirement is to let users free hand draw on top of images and Pdfs and save the files to server. Im using angular 8 and after a quick research, I found that there are many third party packages available which allows free hand drawing and annotation on top of images. Pdfs are a bit more complicated and I didn't find any free plugins for the same .

Are there any plugins available? If there are no options of plugins I was thinking to convert all the pdfs to images first , then draw on the images and save . Is this the best option to go about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render your PDF file in a canvas with [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), then you should draw shapes on top of it.
The repo contains some examples that you should look at.